# Question if an operator is compact

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators

So here is my problem,

Let 
$$J_p:\ell^p\rightarrow c_o$$
be the canonical embedding where $c_0:=\{x_n\subseteq\mathbb C:x_n\rightarrow 0\quad n \rightarrow\infty\}$. I have to decide whether the upper operator is compact. I thought that is indeed compact since one can define,
$$J_p^{(k)}(x_n)=\begin{cases}x_n\quad \text{if}\;n\leq k\\
0\quad\text{else}
\end{cases}$$
and the following holds,
$$||J_p(x_n)-J_p^{(k)}||_p=\sup_{k>n}|x_n|\rightarrow 0\quad k\rightarrow \infty$$
we can conlude that a sequence of finite ranked  operators which in particular are comapact, converges to $J_p$ in the operator norm.

Is my argumentation correct?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems that you first fix an element $(x_n) \in \ell^p$ and then show that $||J_p(x_n) - J^{(k)}_p(x_n)|| \to 0$ as $k\to \infty$. So that is not a convergence in operator norm .

Comment: @John I thought since it holds for every $(x_n)$ is will also holds for the supremum... might be wrong

Comment: $||J_p - J^{(k)}_p|| = \sup_{||x_n||=1} ||J_p(x_n) - J^{(k)}_p(x_n)||$. So for each fixed $k$, if you let $(x_n)$ be the sequence with $x_k=1$ and $x_n= 0$ for $n\neq k$, then it shows that $||J_p - J^{(k)}_p|| \geq 1$.

Comment: Actually by that element $x_n \in \ell^p$, one can show that $J_p$ is not compact.

Comment: @John Can you give me a hint how?

Comment: Let $x^k \in \ell^p$ with only nonzero entry (which is 1) at $n=k$. This is a bounded sequence in $\ell^p$.

Comment: @John Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More generally, none of the natural embeddings $\ell^p\to \ell^q$ for $1\le p<q\le \infty$ are compact. The reason is the same as in the comment by John: the infinite sequence of standard basis vectors $e_n$ is bounded in the  $\ell^p$ norm but is uniformly separated with  respect to  $\ell^q$ norm, hence has no convergent subsequence.